# Is there a more graceful way to find the correct number?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

I have a 2D array that acts as a board for a chess game.  I expect user input to be in the [Smith Notation](https://www.chessclub.com/chessviewer/smith.html).  The way my array is set up is if the user says they want a piece to move to or from the 8th row (the top one from the user's point of view), they are interacting with `row[0]` in the array.  So to handle this I wrote a function that converts the user's input into the correct row for the array.  However, it seems a little clunky and I was wondering how programmers with more experience would solve this problem.

```
int convertToCorrectRow(int row)
{
    int newRow;
    switch (row) {
        case 1:
            newRow = 7;
            break;
        case 2:
            newRow = 6;
            break;
        case 3:
            newRow = 5;
            break;
        case 4:
            newRow = 4;
            break;
        case 5:
            newRow = 3;
            break;
        case 6:
            newRow = 2;
            break;
        case 7:
            newRow = 1;
            break;
        case 8:
            newRow = 0;
            break;            
        default:
            assert(false);
            break;
    }
    return newRow;
}
```

I did think of having flipping the array and displaying it in reverse to the user so that when the user interacts with row 8 they are actually interact with `row[7]` in the array and that would eliminate the need for this function.  However, I would still like to know other ways to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance for your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this simplifies to:

```
int convertToCorrectRow(int row) {
    assert(row > 0 && row <= 8);
    return 8 - row;
}
```

If `row` comes from user input without further validation, I wouldn't use an assert, though.

Comment: Derp. Now I'm embarrassed.  I knew there was a much simpler way to do this, but apparently I was too stupid to think of it ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Why not just...

```
int convertToCorrectRow(int row)
{
    assert(row < 9 && row > 0);
    return 8 - row;
}
```